# Subsonic custom mapping of objects to tables

Tags: .net, orm, poco, subsonic3

I'm using Compact Framework 3.5 and have tentatively settled on a custom build of Subsonic 3.0 to do data access. The trouble is that I am used to developing model-first but am also interested in keeping control of my DB schema. Therefore, neither ActiveRecord or Repository appears to meet my needs, and I want to use my existing POCO model and map it to my existing tables. I'm used to doing this via NHibernate and Entity Framework.

After some investigation, it appears that I might be able to author a custom QueryMapping to give me the custom mapping I want. Before I start down this path, however, I'd like to see some kind of example of this being done. I can't seem to find any on the web, and wonder if anyone could give input on experience with Subsonic, model-first and a custom Table-per-Type and Table-per-Hierarchy mapping.

Answer (score 1):

As of SubSonic 3.0.x:

If you want to use POCOs, you very much want the Repository -- the SimpleRepository in particular. SubSonic only supports a table-per-type model. SubSonic does not support inheritance.  If you want it, you'll have to code it; however, that's not of reach if you're motivated to take it on.

The SimpleRepository does, however, offer a respectable amount of control over schema -- even when using (auto)migrations (which I find quite addictive for POCO-first).  Be sure to checkout the good documentation on the project site, in particular http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_SimpleRepository. Pay attention to the attribute usage.  New attributes are easy to create and integrate to a custom repository service class.

Perhaps the *best* thing about SubSonic's SimpleRepository: it's very easy to extend. Our team has extended it quite a bit (e.g. adding eager-loading support), and overall, we all find it very enjoyable to hack on.  It has a very pleasant design, it's fast, lightweight, and doesn't draw attention to itself.

Best of all, SimpleRepository + Migrations encourage a sane schema design.  If you find yourself fighting SubSonic, you need to check yourself; more likely than not, you're steering your boat into the weeds.

If you need more database versioning firepower, combine it with [migrator.net](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/wiki/GettingStarted) for an easy win.

Good luck, and welcome to SubSonic!